# How to save persistent data through winform update?

Tags: c#, winforms, clickonce

I've a program that creates a profile and posts to social media and as such I've a collection of API keys and Access Tokens for each profile.

I've saved some to the default properties.settings but there is an unknown number of profiles before run time and each would need their own settings file. I've saved some to an XML file but that gets overwritten during updates.

How do I save the data so it doesn't get written over during an update?

Comment: a good approach is to store users setting on the DB

Comment: Hello jmv. Most likely use case scenario is a user creates one profile and maybe posts to a couple of social media accounts. That would be 8 strings for keys and tokens.

DB seems like such epic overkill.

Answer (score 0):

1. It is a good practice to use a database.
2. If you change the location of the file being launched, the old configuration file will not be used, which means that all settings will be unavailable until you return the application to the location from where the initial save was made.
3. If saving tokens without using databases is fundamental for you, then you can use the INI files (example below) or use [Newtonsoft.Json](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Newtonsoft.Json) to save data in JSON format (this is better than INI).

In the example for INI files, I use the package [Hopes.MultiConfX](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Hopex.MultiConfX), saving, updating and receiving tokens works (there is also deletion in the package). Visualization in the screenshot below the code.

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Windows.Forms;

using Hopex.MultiConfX.Ini;

namespace WindowsFormsApp1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        readonly Ini iniHandler = new Ini("tokens");

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            iniHandler.Load();
            cb_users.Items.AddRange(items: iniHandler.Data.GetSections().ToArray());
        }

        private void btn_add_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (
                !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(value: tb_new_user.Text) &&
                !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(value: tb_new_social_network.Text) &&
                !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(value: tb_new_token.Text)
            )
            {
                iniHandler.Data.AddItem(
                    section: tb_new_user.Text,
                    key: tb_new_social_network.Text,
                    value: tb_new_token.Text
                );

                if (iniHandler.Save())
                {
                    cb_users.Items.Clear();
                    cb_social_networks.Items.Clear();
                    tb_token.Text = string.Empty;

                    cb_users.Items.AddRange(items: iniHandler.Data.GetSections().ToArray());

                    MessageBox.Show(text: "Success");
                }
                else
                    MessageBox.Show(text: "Failure");
            }
        }

        private void cb_users_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            cb_social_networks.Items.Clear();
            cb_social_networks.Items.AddRange(
                items: iniHandler.Data.GetKeys(
                    section: ((ComboBox)sender).SelectedItem.ToString()
                ).ToArray()
            );
        }

        private void cb_social_networks_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            tb_token.Text = iniHandler.Data.GetValue(
                section: cb_users.SelectedItem.ToString(),
                key: ((ComboBox)sender).SelectedItem.ToString()
            );
        }
    }
}
```

[image]